# How to make an EqualityComparer compare against two fields?

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, iequalitycomparer

Our code base currently has the following EqualityComparer.

```
    public static IEnumerable<TSource> Exclude<TSource, TKey>(this IEnumerable<TSource> first,
                                                              IEnumerable<TSource> second,
                                                              Func<TSource, TKey> keySelector,
                                                              IEqualityComparer<TKey> comparer = null)
    {
        comparer = comparer ?? EqualityComparer<TKey>.Default;
        var set = new HashSet<TKey>(second.Select(keySelector), comparer);
        return first.Where(item => set.Add(keySelector(item)));
    }
```

And we use it like this.

```
// Take the current model and remove all items currently in the database... This leaves us with only records that need to be added.
var userBooksToAdd = model.UserBooks.Exclude(currentUserBooksFromDatabase, d => d.Id).ToList();
```

We now have the need to compare against two fields in the database where there is a `COMPOSITE UNIQUE`

Basically

```
if(currentBooksFromDatabase.BookId == model.BookId && 
   currentBooksFromDatabase.UserId == model.Id)
```

I'm hoping to create an `Exclude` overload, but I'm really in over my head with the EqualityComparer

Comment: You're okay with building a custom equality comparer right? You're not expecting that the `Default` will somehow do the job?

Comment: Would returning an anonymous object in your key selector work?  `Exclude(currentUserBooksFromDatabase, d => new { d.Id, d.Name })`  Just a guess.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use an anonymous object:

```
var userBooksToAdd = model.UserBooks.Exclude(currentUserBooksFromDatabase, 
    d => new{ d.Id, d.BookId }).ToList();
```

Note that anonymous objects will not use the `Equals` and `GetHashCode` implementations defined in `object`.  They override them to do a memberwise comparison of each of the fields, so this will work as expected.

Comment: Works exactly as expected. I like this approach. Thanks a bunch!